# Converting output of `hg history` into a dot file

Tags: mercurial, scripting, graphviz, dot

How can I take the output of `hg history` and convert it into a [dot](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=3&ved=0CCAQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.graphviz.org%2FDocumentation%2Fdotguide.pdf&ei=XhpZS9_xMZGKNt7bjYkP&usg=AFQjCNGCmvMquSM1wYZ4NTkflZP4_M5JnA&sig2=sWbAt73b6gQCyaYSS8oHOg) file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for [this extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/GraphvizExtension).

Comment: I should have asked this question on SD _before_ trying to hack my own script :)

Comment: @Thr4wn, completely unrelated, but I absolutely dig your avatar xP

Comment: does the extension still work with current hg? (and if you want something very simple, you could use hg debugindexdot)

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a script to do this (and called it hghistory2dot.pl). See its usage below the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "digraph {\n";
$first = 1;
$cset = ();

sub printedge {
    my $one = csetstr(shift(@_));
    my $two = csetstr(shift(@_));
    print $one, " -> ", $two, ";\n";
}

sub csetstr {
    my $csetid = shift(@_);
    $csetid =~ s/\s//;
    $csetid =~ s/\\n//;
    return "cset_" . $csetid;
}

while($line = <> ) {
    if (!($line eq "\n") ) {
    $line =~ s/\n/\\n/;
    push(@cset, $line);
    }
    else {
    print csetstr($current), " [shape=record label=\"", @cset, "\"];\n";
    @cset = ();
    }

    if( $line =~ m/^changeset/ ) {
    @arr = split(/:/, $line);
    $arr[2] =~ s/\s//;

    if( ! $parent_found && ! $first) {
        #previous changeset had no defined parent; therefore this one is the implied parent.
        printedge($current, $arr[2]);
    }

    $current = $arr[2];

    $parent_found = 0;
    $first = 0;
    }
    elsif($line =~ m/^parent/) {
    $parent_found = 1;
    @arr = split(/:/, $line);
    $arr[2] =~ s/\s//;
    printedge($current, $arr[2]);
    }
}

print "}\n";
```

`hg history | hghistory2dot.pl | dot -Tpng > tree.png`